# unique nested ng-repeat populated from database

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am trying to get unique values for a nested ng-repeat

there are the two scopes i am working with

```
$scope.AllGames = [ 
   { title: "Doom", productCode: "458544", id_product: "1" }, 
   { title: "Wolvenstein", productCode: "457104", id_product: "2" }, 
   { title: "Quake", productCode: "32542687", id_product: "3" } 
];

$scope.AllPrices= [ 
   { id_productPrice: "1", id_product: "1", price : "599" }, 
   { id_productPrice: "2", id_product: "1", price : "699" }, 
   { id_productPrice: "3", id_product: "2", price : "249" } 
];
```

this is the html

```
<div ng-repeat="game in AllGames">
    <div>{{game.title}} | {{game.id_product}} | {{game.title}}</div>
    <div ng-init="getPriceByGame(game.id_product)">

    <div ng-repeat="item in AllPrices">
            {{item.price}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the controller

```
    $scope.getAllGames = function () {
        var request = 'Games';
        $http({
            method: 'Get',
            url: uri + request
        })
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.AllGames = data;
           })

    }

    $scope.getPriceByGame = function (id_product) {
    var request = AllPrices/' + id_product;

        $http({
            method: 'Get',
            url: uri + request
        })
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.AllPrices = data;
            })
    };
```

So the idea is that i send the id_product to the database and i get a list of prices back for that id, i would like to connect these prices for each unique product. what happens now is that the ng-init works fine and the request gets send with the id, i receive the prices for that id. In the console log i see all the prices coming in by product_id (all different arrays) but i can't seem to connect them in the html so i actually see the prices.

The last request overwrites of course all the prices for each game in the ng-repeat. How do i keep this unique? So that each product gets the prices for that id.

Answer (score 0):

You could place another ng repeat to loop through the all Prices array. Every time you get new data, you push it to the array.

Don't forget to make an edit in the nested ng repeat of all prices, it should loop only through the current index

Comment: hi there, i dont want to alter the array i would like to read them